# Netifly Redirect within same root folder in subfolders

Tags: netlify

html on different folders like this:

Folder:

```
   index.html
   startup  <--This one is another folder
```

Then on startup folder I have another index.html
I´m using the netlify.toml like this:

```
[[redirects]]
  from = "/"
  to = "/startup/index.html"
  status = 301
```

This file is on my startup folder, but when I

Answer (score 0):

It should be with
force = true
adding this to the above code worked for me :)